# Numpy getter/setter of arrays of different dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I want:

if `x` is one-dimensional, return `x[I]`

if `x` is two-dimensional, return `x[i,:]`

if `x` is three-dimensional, return `x[i, j, :]`

...

`x`'s are numpy arrays

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self, x):
       self.x = x  # an n-d array

   def pop_q(q, tuple):
       q = zeros(tuple)

   def set_q(q, i, j=None, qq):
       if q.ndim == 1:
           q[i] = qq
       else if q.ndim == 2:
           q[i, :] = qq
       else if q.ndim == 3:
           q[i, j, :] = qq

   def get_q(q, i, j=None):
       if q.ndim == 1:
           return q[i]
       else if q.ndim == 2:
           return q[i, :]
       else if q.ndim == 3:
           return q[i, j, :]
```

But is there better way of writing this? (using `*args` perhaps, to arbitrary dimensional array)

The reason I'm doing this encapsulation is to ensure modularity

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
def get_q(self, i, j=None):
    slicing = (i, j, slice(None))[:self.x.ndim]
    return self.x[slicing]
```

Remember slice(None) corresponds to `:`

So I make a tuple corresponding to (i, j, :), but I keep only the first self.x.ndim elements of this tuple

If you want a solution that works with any number of dimensions:

```
def get_q(self, *indices):
    slicing = (indices + (slice(None),) * self.x.ndim)[:self.x.ndim]
    return self.x[slicing]
```

Setter should work exactly the same way.

Comment: How about setter? Can you also provide?

Comment: I edited my answer (I had made a couple of errors)

Setters should work the same way. I let you try

Comment: Setter doesn't work very well because of mutability. Do you have better suggestion?